# Why do some versions of php seem to treat unicode as unprintable

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I ran the following code sample on 3v4l.org at https://3v4l.org/bUqlj

```
<?php

var_dump(preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/u', 'x', "你"));
```

and it seems that some old versions of php are returning "x". This seems to be incorrect behaviour. I tried to see if this behaviour was documented somewhere online, but couldn't find it.

Comment: What script is that ?

Comment: @noob https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a result of a PCRE issue. The output on 3V4L shows that things started working in the v5.4 series after v5.4.41, and in the v5.5 series after v5.5.10.

Now, looking at the PHP changelogs:

- PHP v5.4.41 [upgraded PCRE to v8.37](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.41) ([previously v8.32](https://3v4l.org/jL7FK))
- PHP v5.5.10 [upgraded PCRE to v8.34](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.10) ([previously v8.32](https://3v4l.org/jL7FK))

So the upgrade away from PCRE v8.32 fixed the issue (note that the v5.6 series started with PCRE v8.34 in v5.6.0). Looking at the [PCRE changelog](http://www.pcre.org/original/changelog.txt), we see under the `Version 8.34 15-December-2013` section, item 31:

> Upgraded the handling of the POSIX classes [:graph:], [:print:], and [:punct:] when PCRE_UCP is set so as to include the same characters as Perl does in Unicode mode.

This looks to be the change that fixed your test case.

Comment: One thing to add: `\P{C}` [is equivalent to](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) `[:print:]` when the unicode modifier is in use, so `/[^\P{C}]/u` should achieve the same as `/[^[:print:]]/u` but [work across all versions](https://3v4l.org/GqaYE).

Comment: thanks @nj_! I was suspecting that exact changelog entry after running some tests with `pcregrep` directly with those regexes